# I'm getting this output: #<Bitly::V3::Url:0x202ea38> instead of the shortened URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am using the bitly gem in rails 3
I am trying to post URL in shortened form to Twitter

my Gemfile

```
gem "bitly", :git => 'https://github.com/philnash/bitly/'
gem 'omniauth-bitly', :git => 'https://github.com/michaeldelorenzo/omniauth-bitly.git'
```

config\initializers\bitly.rb

```
Bitly.configure do |config|
  config.api_version = 3
  config.login = "username"
  config.api_key = "x_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
end
```

I'm using this to use Bitly

```
      Bitly.use_api_version_3
      bitly = Bitly.client
      bitly.shorten("http://domain.com/articles/#{id}")
```

but when I check on Twitter, this is the output

```
#<Bitly::V3::Url:0x202ea38>
```

How is preventing the shortened URL form to show?

When I log into my account on Bitly, I see that it worked and it shows the conversions there... but the URL is not posted to Twitter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the example from the gems documentation

```
u = bitly.shorten('http://www.google.com') #=> Bitly::Url

u.long_url #=> "http://www.google.com"
u.short_url #=> "http://bit.ly/Ywd1"
u.bitly_url #=> "http://bit.ly/Ywd1"
u.jmp_url #=> "http://j.mp/Ywd1"
u.user_hash #=> "Ywd1"
u.hash #=> "2V6CFi"
u.info #=> a ruby hash of the JSON returned from the API
u.stats #=> a ruby hash of the JSON returned from the API
```

Based on this your result is expected. if you want the short url try

```
bitly.shorten("http://domain.com/articles/#{id}").short_url
```